Passing Streams to and from a Function (flutter_libserialport data to COBS decoder)
I've been trying to get the COBS 0.2.0 decodeCOBSStream function working.  I'm sending data from the PC's Bluetooth connection from a Hercules terminal program (HEX values with CR/LF disabled) to an HC-05 Bluetooth module connected to a USB port thru an FTDI cable.  flutter_libserialport does fine with the raw values, I can print them to the debug console and everything looks fine.
However, when I try passing the stream to decodeCOBSStream and printing it out, the first message prints fine.  Sometimes the second one does.  Then it stops printing the messages and eventually the the read routine of flutter_libserialport throws an exception at the return statement.
ArgumentError (Invalid argument(s): length must be in the range [0, 4611686018427387903].)
This is the function in question from flutter_libserialport:
static Uint8List read(int bytes, UtilFunc<ffi.Uint8> readFunc) {
    return ffi.using((arena) {
      final ptr = arena<ffi.Uint8>(bytes);
      final len = call(() => readFunc(ptr));
      return Uint8List.fromList(ptr.asTypedList(len));
    });
  }

Here is my code.  If I create a lister that sends the values coming from upcomingData to onDataReceived (changing it to take Uint8List as input), it's fine.  I'm pretty sure it's the way I'm putting decodeCOBSStream in between it.  flutter_libserialport works with Uint8List and decodeCOBSStream works with ByteData.
import 'dart:typed_data';
import 'dart:async';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_libserialport/flutter_libserialport.dart';
import 'package:cobs2/cobs2.dart';

const kDebugMode = true;

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  @override
  State<MyApp> createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    List<String> availablePort = SerialPort.availablePorts;
    SerialPort port = SerialPort('COM4');
    SerialPortReader reader = SerialPortReader(port);
    final controller = StreamController<ByteData>();

    debugPrint('Available Ports: $availablePort');

/*    
    Stream<ByteData> upcomingData = reader.stream.map((data) {
      ByteData byteData = data.buffer.asByteData();
      return byteData;
    });
*/
    // Received the serial data from the SerialPortReader 'reader'
    Stream<Uint8List> upcomingData = reader.stream.map((data) {
      return data;
    });

    controller.addStream(decodeCOBSStream(upcomingData.byteData));

    // When data is received
    void onDataReceived(ByteData data) {
      var decodeUint8 = data.buffer.asUint8List();
      var decodedPrt =
          getHexString(decodeUint8, offset: 0, length: decodeUint8.length);
      debugPrint('Decoded: $decodedPrt');
    }

/*    // When data is received
    void onDataReceived(Uint8List data) {
      var decodedPrt = getHexString(data, offset: 0, length: data.length);
      debugPrint('Decoded: $decodedPrt');
    }
*/
    try {
      port.openReadWrite();
      initSerial(port);

      // Send data to serial port
      serialSend(port, 'Ready for data!');

      // Creates a listener to receive the decoded data
      //controller.stream.listen((data) => onDataReceived(data));
      controller.stream.listen(onDataReceived).onDone(() {});
      //upcomingData.listen(onDataReceived).onDone(() {});
    } on SerialPortError catch (err, _) {
      debugPrint('${SerialPort.lastError}');
      port.close();
    }

    return Container();
  }
}

extension on Stream<Uint8List> {
  Stream<ByteData> get byteData => transform(Uint8ListToByteData());
}

// Stream transformer that converts Uint8List data to ByteData.
class Uint8ListToByteData extends StreamTransformerBase<Uint8List, ByteData> {
  @override
  Stream<ByteData> bind(Stream<Uint8List> stream) {
    return stream.map((data) => data.buffer.asByteData());
  }
}

Uint8List _stringToUint8List(String data) {
  List<int> codeUnits = data.codeUnits;
  Uint8List uint8list = Uint8List.fromList(codeUnits);
  return uint8list;
}

// Converts a String of multiple integers into HEX
String getHexString(
  List<int> list, {
  required int offset,
  required int length,
}) {
  var sublist = list.getRange(offset, offset + length);
  return [
    for (var byte in sublist)
      byte.toRadixString(16).padLeft(2, '0').toUpperCase()
  ].join();
}

void initSerial(SerialPort port) {
  var config = port.config;
  config.baudRate = 9600;
  config.bits = 8;
  config.stopBits = 1;
  config.parity = 0;
  port.config = config;

  debugPrint('BaudRate = 9600');
}

void serialSend(SerialPort port, String data) {
  debugPrint('Written Bytes: ${port.write(_stringToUint8List(data))}');
}

I've tried passing the data different ways to flutter_libserialport.  I've tried changing it from Uint8List to ByteData in the upcomingData function and I've tried using stream transformers to do it.  Some of the variations I've tried are shown, but commented out.

The cobs code is, well, old and could be improved. Give that the whole library is in one source file and fits on about 2 pages, you can easily re-write it to work on typed data instead of ByteData. I'd suggest you add your received bytes to a ByteDataReader. You can then easily read one byte at a time finding the 0x00 delimiter and processing the bytes between delimiters.

That is what I originally was working towards.  I had a buffer that I was adding to as data was received. I haven't played with a ByteDataReader before.  Can you point me to a good example?

Would it be worthwhile just using the Buffer package for that.  Seems to make use of ByteDataReader.

Yes, that's where it is defined. You need somewhere that you can dump the incoming raw bytes and then read them out little by little as you strip off the cobs ornamentation.

ByteDataReader is a useful class to gather bytes that you will process little-by-little. This allows you to add bytes as they come over the wire. It has another feature to 'block' if there are not enough bytes to form a complete message - i.e. in your case if there isn't a zero byte delimiter yet.
This allows us to take the Wikipedia example C code and quickly implement an async method that returns a complete message, once one is available. Wrapping that in an async* method yields a stream of such messages, as bytes are added.
A complete working example is shown below:
import 'dart:typed_data';

import 'package:buffer/buffer.dart';
import 'package:convert/convert.dart';

void main() async {
  final reader = ByteDataReader(copy: true);
  cobsDecode(reader).listen((o) => print(o));

  reader.add(hex.decode('01010100'));
  reader.add(hex.decode('031122023300'));
  reader.add(hex.decode('031122')); // the above block split in 2
  reader.add(hex.decode('023300'));

  // add some more bytes later
  Future.delayed(
    Duration(seconds: 2),
    () => reader.add(hex.decode('031122023300')),
  );
}

Stream<Uint8List> cobsDecode(ByteDataReader reader) async* {
  while (true) {
    yield await _readBlock(reader);
  }
}

Future<Uint8List> _readBlock(ByteDataReader reader) async {
  final output = BytesBuilder();
  var code = 0xff;
  var block = 0;
  while (true) {
    await reader.readAhead(1); // ensure at least one byte available
    if (block != 0) {
      output.addByte(reader.readUint8()); // todo - add non-zero check
      block--;
    } else {
      block = reader.readUint8();
      if (block != 0 && code != 0xff) {
        output.addByte(0);
      }
      code = block;
      if (code == 0) {
        break;
      }
      block--;
    }
  }
  return output.toBytes();
}

Note that this simple example does not have some typical error handling, like checking that there are no zeros inside a block.
Adding efficiency, such as reading block bytes from the reader in one go, is left as an exercise for the reader.

Thanks!  That's a nice example!  I needed to re-order a few things the main, and print the result in hex to understand it, but I'm getting it (mostly C background... so I still think a sequentially).  I need to play with _readBlock a bit to fully digest this before trying to integrate the concepts into my code.

How does one check the individual elements in the ByteBuilder for a value?  Like 0 at the end?  Also, is there a way to remove elements, like the removeAt or removeLast methods for Uint8List?

So, await reader.readAhead(1); makes it so that only one byte will be processed at a time?  Or, is that just how ByteReader works?  The function taking it as an input only gets 1 byte at a time to process?

Note that there's a difference between ByteBuilder and BytesBuilder. I just used the Dart built in one. In either case there's no way to inspect elements as you are building bytes in a bytes builder. You just shove them in, then call toBytes at the end. In this code, I'm just using the builder as a way to store the output as I parse the input.  Comparing to the Wikipedia C Impl that's the equivalent of @param data Pointer to decoded output data.

While decoding, I'm not interested in what I've already produced, just in the next input byte. If you want to manipulate the end result, wait until after calling toBytes when you have a Uint8List.

Yes, I process one byte at a time from the input to the output - just like the Wikipedia code. (I assume you aren't processing megabytes of data! so no need to prematurely optimize.) The Dart code needs some way to "wait" if a complete message hasn't yet been received. This is the purpose of await reader.readAhead(1); which says, wait until there is at least one byte available in the input. The actual byte is read from the input using reader.readUint8() which reads the next byte from the input (and would throw if the input was empty).

It will probably be around under 1k of data total in the packet.  Likely half of that.  Ah, so the reader.readUint8() is what is limiting how many bytes are being pulled at a time?  I assume there is a way to pull blocks of byte in order to optimize the code as you allude to under the example.

Correct - compare this to read which reads N bytes from the input. So, if you know you want to pull the next 10 bytes in one go (and you've awaited readAhead(10) so you know they are available) simply call reader.read(10). Frankly, with a few kb of data, it's barely worth it. Good news is you have a functionally correct version to compare with, plus the package:cobs code to read and learn from. (BTW, at this point you should 'accept' the answer if it was useful.)

Yes, this was very informative and pointed me in the right direction.  Thank you!
